# knitr figure produced twice (with R 3.0.0)

Tags: r, knitr

I have an Rnw file, which worked fine before upgrading to R 3.0.0 (and knitr 1.2). I found a similar problem described in [knitr problem after update to R 3.0.0](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108335/knitr-problem-after-update-to-r-3-0-0)

I followed the answer, to update to `knitr 1.2.4` (rforge version). The problem persists!

Now, one chunk causes a problem (and one chunk only), which produces two figures. The chunk is called `plotc`, and both `plotc1.pdf` and `plotc2.pdf` are produced. After knitting, pdflatex throws the error:

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file c:/repos/uws-r-manual/figure/plotc1.pdf): PDF inclusion: required page does not exist <0> ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

If needed, I can give access to the bitbucket repo if someone wants to reproduce/fix this problem.

Comment: Yes, please show me an example. My bitbucket id is `stat`, but it's better to post a minimal version of it here. I know a temporary workaround is `<<fig.keep='last'>>=`, but that does not cure the real illness.

Comment: I will invite you to the repo, and attempt at a minimal version. The fit.keep='last' does fix it!

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the problem in the development version (v1.2.5). See [here](https://github.com/yihui/knitr#readme) for instructions on installation. It will go to the stable version 1.3 eventually.

Comment: Version 1.2.5 fixes the problem!